# Not able to get message which contain the double inverted comma

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

In below javascript code

```
      var descriptionOfProduct = $("#descriptionOfProductContainer").clone();
        $(descriptionOfProduct).find("input#hdnDescriptionOfProduct").val(description);
       descriptionOfProduct.find("div#descriptionInEllipsis").html(description);
        return descriptionOfProduct.html();
```

This is ok while showing on UI, but we submit the form in MVC and if In "description" contain double inverted comma then I'm not getting same value in ActionResult.e.g -  Test "homemade" or "Readymade"; the in Action result I'm getting on till test.

Comment: what is `description`? A variable or string?

Comment: @randomSoul - its string getting from kendo grid